# Java/Hibernate-Try to start my web application and an java.lang.ClassNotFoundException occurs

Tags: java, hibernate

I have tried to run my first web application using Hibernate,
 (I started to learn how to use Hibernate only for a week, so be clement :( ) but I've a *ClassNotFoundException* and I don't understand the stack trace.

Can you help me?

```html
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [it.tgi.cd.servlet2.CDOperationServlet2] in context with path [/CDStoreHibernateSpring] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
 at it.tgi.cd.connection2.DBConnection2.openConnection(DBConnection2.java:15)
 at it.tgi.cd.dao2.CDDAO2.searchCD(CDDAO2.java:17)
 at it.tgi.cd.servlet2.CDOperationServlet2.doGet(CDOperationServlet2.java:48)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: ClassNotFoundException is pretty clear in my opinion, what exactly you don't understand about it?

Comment: be patient with me that I'm not very good at programming...where I should do it?

Comment: Huh? I'm just asking: what exactly you don't understand about "Class Not Found" so we can clarify that for you :) Sorry if I sounded rude, that was not my intention.

Comment: Nono I'm sorry, I can not write very well in English eheh I don't understand why it doesn't found that class..

Comment: Because some classes load other classes dynamically at runtime, not at compile time (in Java this is called [reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)). This allows things like plugins. In this case `DBConnection2` cannot found this class the class `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`. Where do you have this class, can you find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying the hibernate jar files into WEB-INF\lib folder,
just clean build to be sure and try again

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I try the solution of acearch and now it run!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss the `hibernate-<version>.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The missing class is in the hibernate-tools package. You can find the jar here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-tools

Just make sure you use the proper version

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jens and I would approach it like this:

1. Adopt a build system like [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/))
2. Put the [Hibernate dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-core%7C4.3.10.Final%7Cjar) in your build file with your project
3. Build it

If you do these things, the build system will pull down Hibernate for you.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when your hibernate jar files has not been **exported** with your web archive.

You can follow below steps if you are using Eclipse.

Right click the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

In the list at left side click on Deployment Assembly. Click "Add" button. Select "Java Build Path Entries" and click next.

Now select your **hibernate jar files** or library. Click finish. Then click Ok. 
Restart the server if necessary.